# TimeOut во время работы с прокси

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, proxy, timeout

```
import requests as r

proxies= {'http': '188.94.231.65:8080'}
p = r.get('http://api.ipify.org/', proxies=proxies).text
print(p)
```

Этот код по идее должен выдать `188.94.231.65`, но спустя 20-30 секунд, выходит ошибка `TimeOut`, я попробовал с другим прокси, но результат тот же.
Все прокси я [беру от сюда](https://api.proxyscrape.com/?request=displayproxies&proxytype=http&country=RU):

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в словарь ключ https, на всякий, и к адресам - протоколы (http:// и https://):

```
import requests

proxies= {
    'http': 'http://109.172.57.64:8081', 
    'https': 'https://109.172.57.64:8081'
}

r = requests.get('http://api.ipify.org/', proxies=proxies)
print(r.content)
```

вернуло:

```
b'217.147.***.***' # тут мой текущий ip
```

т.к. прокси - не анонимные, через них видно ваш ip...

Если прокси анонимный, api.ipify.org вернет что-то типа

```
b'<html><body>It works! =)</body></html>\r\n'
```

PS взял 109.172.57.64:8081 с ресурса, на который вы ссылаетесь, т.к. 188.94.231.65:8080 уже не отвечает: "побочный эффект" бесплатного списка прокси